# argument out of range exception for datagridview c#

Tags: c#, database, arguments

I am getting error during data show on DataGridView
I think this is related -1 issue but how can I handle this 3 condition I could not achieved.
When data count is 3 no problem.

When data count is 2 or 1 program is giving error like argument out of range exception.

```
            ...
        DataTable abc = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(abc);

        DataGridView.DataSource = abc;


        if (Convert.ToString(DataGridView.Rows[0].Cells["xyz"].Value) != null  && Convert.ToString(DataGridView.Rows[1].Cells["xyz"].Value) != null  && Convert.ToString(DataGridView.Rows[2].Cells["xyz"].Value) != null)
        {
            textbox1.Text = Convert.ToString(DataGridView.Rows[0].Cells["xyz"].Value);
            textbox2.Text = Convert.ToString(DataGridView.Rows[1].Cells["xyz"].Value);
            textbox3.Text = Convert.ToString(DataGridView.Rows[2].Cells["xyz"].Value);



            ...
```

Comment: What is `DataGridView.Rows.Count` ?

Comment: You should check DataGridView.Rows.Count before accessing them.

Comment: 3 as mostly but it can be 2 ,1 and 0 according to our combobox selection

Comment: Can you give me an example I saw somethings on internet but could not achieved to implement.

Comment: if it can be 0 1 or 2, then you cannot call .cells on a null. DataGridView.Rows[2] will be null if count = 2 and if its null, you cannot call .Cells on it.

Comment: Sorry, So I mean 4 different values (one of them like you said null). Now I solved like  textbox.Text = ***.Rows.Count.ToString(); and if statement. Thanks for your helps.